# Grafana datalink with variable

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I m having a grafana instance where all the products in a namespace are listed. There are datalinks to logs and to the product configured. The context root of the product is saved as a label in the pod. How do i use the label as a variable in datalinks.

I have tried setting a variable, but the variable is dependent on two other variables, and one of them is not available when variable context root is used.

Variable definition :

```
label_values(kube_pod_labels{namespace="awl-${umgebung}", label_group="awl", label_type="as",label_product="${product}"}, label_context_root)
```

[image: Variable definition]

Then I m using the datalink, `https://xyz.xom/${umgebung}/${context_root}/`. The var `umgebung` is available as it is always selected to display the products from one particular environment. But the var `$product` is not selected and so `$context_root` doesnt know what to return. How can edit the variable `context_root` to use the label_product.

The metrics used in the field `(label_replace(sum by (label_product) (kube_pod_labels{namespace="awl-${umgebung}", label_group="awl", label_product="${product}"}), "toshow", "    $1 - AS   ", "label_product", "(.*)"))`

What other possibilites exist for me to provide the product URL which is created from the context root saved in the labels of the pods

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using merge with a second query the variable from the secong query can be used in the datalinks.

So my second query:

`(label_replace (kube_pod_labels{namespace="awl-${umgebung}", label_group="awl", label_product="${product}", label_type="as"}, "product_link", "https://some_website/${umgebung}/$1", "label_context_root", "^(.*)$"))`

Format : Table

Datalink

`${__data.fields[product_link]}`

In the transform tab, a simple merge is used.